# Accumulate up and down

Tags: associations, functional-style, algorithm

I want to accumulate positive and negative values separately.

```
dt = RandomSample[Range[-10, 10]]
```

{3, -5, 2, -9, 1, -1, 0, 8, 10, 4, -7, 7, -8, -3, 6, -4, -2, 5, -10, -6, 9}

To remember positions:

```
as = AssociationThread[Range @ Length @ dt -> dt];
```

Helper function because `Accumulate` doesn't map over `Association`s:

```
cum[x_] := AssociationThread[Keys[x] -> Accumulate @ Values[x]]
```

Result:

```
res = Values @ KeySort[<|cum @ Select[# >= 0 &] @ as, cum @ Select[# < 0 &] @ as|>]
```

{3, -5, 5, -14, 6, -15, 6, 14, 24, 28, -22, 35, -30, -33, 41, -37, -39, 46, -49, -55, 55}

```
res // ListPlot
```

[image]

**My question:**

Which shorter / better / faster ways do exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
accumulateUpDown := Module[{ud = {0, 0}}, Map[ud[[1 + Boole[# >= 0]]] += # &]]

accumulateUpDown @ dt == res
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
accumulateUpDown2 := Module[{u = 0, d = 0}, Map[If[# >= 0, u += #, d += #] &]]

accumulateUpDown2 @ dt == res
```

> True

Comment: `accumulateUpDown2` is simple, nice  and surprising at the same time

Comment: You should probably use `:=` or at least explain in your solution that `accumulateUpDown` will only work once. The `Module` variables are kept around and will cause unexpected results on repeated application.

Comment: Thank you @lericr. Very good point. Updated.

Comment: `accumulateUpDown4 := Module[{u = 0, d = 0}, Map[If[# >= 0, u += #, d += #] &]];` would also fix the problem and has better readability.

Comment: `ud[[Sign@#]]` is a little simpler

Comment: @att, thank you. Tried `Sign`; but there are 0's in the input list.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to accept `accumulateUpDown2`

Comment: Thank you @eldo. BTW, for large lists, `f` from [my other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289891/125) is much faster.

Answer (score 7):

You could use SubsetMap after creating a way to discrimate between negative and non-negative:

```
SubsetMap[Accumulate, Position[dt, _?NonNegative]]@*
  SubsetMap[Accumulate, Position[dt, _?Negative]]@dt
```

Comment: Also: `Module[{f = SubsetMap[Accumulate, Position[dt, _?#]] &}, 
 f[NonNegative]@*f[Negative]@dt]`

Comment: I'd probably use `With` instead of `Module`, but yeah, that's a nice way to improve readability.

Comment: Also, since the predicates are discrete and exhaustive, we could use a logical negation rather than use two predicates.

Answer (score 6):

just another way -- faster than alternatives posted so far:

```
f = Module[{m = UnitStep @ #}, 
     m # + (m - 1) #2 & @@ Map[Accumulate] @ Ramp @ {# , -#}] &;


f @ dt == res
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
Accumulate@Ramp@# UnitStep@#&[acl] - Accumulate@Ramp@# Sign@Ramp@#&[-acl]

(* {3,-5,5,-14,6,-15,6,14,24,28,-22,35,-30,-33,41,-37,-39,46,-49,-55,55} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
alist = {3, -5, 2, -9, 1, -1, 0, 8, 10, 4, -7, 7, -8, -3, 6, -4, -2, 
  5, -10, -6, 9}

accUpDn[k_List] := First@Last@Reap@
    FoldList[
     If[#2 >= 0, {Sow[#1[[1]] + #2], #1[[2]]}
       , {#[[1]], Sow[#1[[2]] + #2]}
       ] &
     , {0, 0} (*starting value, separate +ve/-ve counters *)
     , k
     ]

accUpDn[alist]
```

> {3, -5, 5, -14, 6, -15, 6, 14, 24, 28, -22, 35, -30, -33, 41, -37, 
> -39, 46, -49, -55, 55}

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [@kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289891/26956), branchless

```
ints = {3, -5, 2, -9, 1, -1, 0, 8, 10, 4, -7, 7, -8, -3, 6, -4, -2, 
  5, -10, -6, 9} ;
expected = {3, -5, 5, -14, 6, -15, 6, 14, 24, 28, -22, 35, -30, -33, 
  41, -37, -39, 46, -49, -55, 55} ;

accumulateUpDown = 
 With[{picker = UnitStep[#], acc = Accumulate[#], accAbs = Accumulate[Abs[#]]},
    (picker (acc + accAbs) + (1 - picker) (acc - accAbs))/2] & ;

accumulateUpDown[ints] == expected
```

> True

**EDIT**

As it turns out, dividing by two unpacks arrays, hurting performance. For packed integer arrays a much faster version is

```
accumulateUpDown = 
 With[{picker = UnitStep[#], acc = Accumulate[#], accAbs = Accumulate[Abs[#]]},
    BitShiftRight[picker (acc + accAbs) + (1 - picker) (acc - accAbs)]] & ;
```